# Sockets vs Metro WS-Security complexity

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, ws-security

I implement Java server application which should work with number of clients and provide requested information from database. This information is client specific. From my point of view I had a choice between socket connection and web services. Web services looked quite natural for this kind of task. I started looking for information about web services with username/password authentication and came to WS-Security. And then things became very complex.

I use Metro. Its manual requires to install NetBeans, GlassFish and perform configuration via NetBeans GUI. I installed it and was a bit confused by a lot of options and settings related to WS-Security. To ensure everything is going right I need the message to be signed up and encrypted. For that I need a bunch of public/private keys and certificates which should be delivered to client. When new client registers I have to update keystore, generate new keys and certs and so on. My data isn't that secret. It's just online game character parameters and I don't actually need all that stuff with privacy and encryption. I assume that username and password is enough. I also read that encryption produces big overhead on message handling and in case of big load I'm afraid it can become performance bottleneck.

So I'm a bit confused about futher dealing with WS-Security and ask your advice. Is it good scenario for using WS at all or better implement it with sockets? Do I need WS-Security here? If so are certs and keys a big deal here? Because at the moment it looks very complex (probably because I'm very tired of reading all those security specs, encryption details and so on).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

WS-* is very heavyweight, so don't feel bad about being confused by it. On the other hand, I think sockets are bit bare. Why not try REST, secured by HTTP Basic authentication, encrypted with HTTPS? There should be plenty of tutorials on the web to follow.

Comment: I need to pass complex data, that's why I chose SOAP.

Comment: REST is more than capable of passing complex XML